# GPU Memory Almost Full, but Utilization Stuck at 0% – How to Resolve?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

[image: img]

I'm facing an issue with my GPU. My GPU memory is nearly fully occupied, yet the utilization remains consistently at 0%. I'm using a A40, and my drivers are up-to-date.

Here is the code related to data loading

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
import utils.constants as constants
from utils.preprocess_data import *


def parse_tfrecord_fn(example_proto):
    feature_description = {
        'elevation': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'pdsi': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'NDVI': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'pr': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'sph': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'th': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'tmmn': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'tmmx': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'vs': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'erc': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'population': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'PrevFireMask': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),
        'FireMask': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([64, 64], tf.float32),  # Assuming binary (fire or no fire)
        # Add more features based on your actual dataset
    }

    example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
    return example


class TFRecordDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, tfrecord_pattern):
        # Use tf.data.Dataset.list_files to match files using a pattern
        file_list = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(tfrecord_pattern)
        # Use flat_map to create a dataset from the files
        self.dataset = file_list.flat_map(
            lambda file: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file)
        ).map(
            parse_tfrecord_fn
        )
        self.example  = list(self.dataset)

    def __len__(self):
        # Use tf.data.Dataset.reduce to compute the total number of elements
        return self.dataset.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()


    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        example  = self.example[idx]

        all_features = []
        # Convert TensorFlow tensors to PyTorch tensors
        for f in (constants.INPUT_FEATURES + constants.OUTPUT_FEATURES):
            min_val, max_val, mean, std = constants.DATA_STATS[f]
            if f in ('PrevFireMask', 'FireMask'):
                all_features.append(torch.tensor(example[f].numpy(), dtype=torch.int))
            else:
                all_features.append(torch.tensor(example[f].numpy(), dtype=torch.float32))
            # all_features.append(torch.tensor(example[f].numpy(), dtype=torch.float32))
            all_features[-1] = torch.clamp(all_features[-1], min_val, max_val)
            all_features[-1] = (all_features[-1] - mean) / std
        sample = torch.cat([f.unsqueeze(0) for f in all_features[:len(constants.INPUT_FEATURES)]])
        return {'feature':sample,'label':all_features[-1].unsqueeze(0)}
```

I have looked for some solutions online, and it's suggested that the issue might be related to data reading efficiency. Since I am working on a deep learning project using PyTorch, the dataset I am using is in the .tfrecord format, which can only be read by TensorFlow. To work around this, I first use TensorFlow to read the raw data and then transform it into a format usable by PyTorch in a custom DataLoader class.

I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem, but if it is, how should I go about resolving it?

Comment: Are you running into OOM issues?